# Watch for a variable change Angular

Tags: angular

How do I do this piece of code from React on Angular?

```
let var;

//watch for var changes
useEffect(() => {
   console.log(var)
}, [var])
```

Comment: Angular is module based and it works with rxjs for the implementation of the Observable pattern and with many libs (the most famous is Ngrx) for the Redux pattern. You have to understand how https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services work and then see https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/subject. 

With that you will have an idea how your workflow will be. There is no 1on1 translation between the 2 because the scopes are different depending on your https://angular.io/guide/architecture-modules structure

Comment: I'm not doing a big project, so I wont pass this variable to the whole project. Just want to listen this variable on a single file. Still have to implement all of it?

Comment: As the answer  above from @viniciusmfelix says, `we actually don't have a 'native' state watcher as React does`. You can use 2way binding and listen to `(ngModelChange)` or you have to implement a Service (probably Singleton) with a `Subject` and subscribe to subject's changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Angular, we use two-way data binding to achieve this purpose. With that in mind, we actually don't have a 'native' state watcher as React does.

So, to watch every changes on a variable that is declared on your component class, you have to wrap it using interpolation, like: `{{variable}}`.

You can play with two-way data binding add a `<input>` tag and adding the directive `[(ngModel)]` pointing to your component class property and directive `(ngModelChange)` to execute one function every time that your variable is modified. Here's one example:

**component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent {
 variable: string;

 execute() {
  console.log('Executed!');
 }
}
```

**component.html**

```
<label for="interpolate">Interpolating:</label>
<input name="interpolate" id="interpolate" type="text" [(ngModel)]="variable" (ngModelChange)="execute()"/>
<h1>{{variable}}</h1>
```

To test this example, don't forget to add the *FormsModule* import on your `app.module.ts`:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```